# Using build tasks with multitarget solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, msbuild-task

I've got a basic build task example for a C# project using VS2019, which works as expected when I'm targeting a single framework such as `net48`

```cs
public class MyTask : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task
{
  public override bool Execute()
  {
    Log.LogMessage("Hey I ran!");
    return true;
  }
}
```

my csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<UsingTask TaskName="MyTask" AssemblyFile="bin\Debug\net48\MyAssembly.dll" />
<Target Name="SomeTask" AfterTargets="Build>
  <MyTask />
</Target>
```

however if I try to multitarget my app (needed for a well used nuget package I distribute) the task fails to run. I've tried adding variables and even some conditions but it always fails to either not find the task assembly or the task itself.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyTask" AssemblyFile="bin\Debug\$(TargetFramework)\MyAssembly.dll" />
<UsingTask TaskName="MyTask" AssemblyFile="bin\Debug\net48\MyAssembly.dll" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net48'" />
```

the error when multitarget is enabled:

> MyProject.csproj(71,3): error MSB4036: The "MyTask" task was not
> found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project
> file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is
> "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface.
> 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.200" directory.

the error when trying to resolve the assembly:

> MyProject.csproj(70,3): error MSB4062: The "MyTask" task could not be
> loaded from the assembly B:..\bin\Release\MyAssembly.dll. Could not
> load file or assembly 'B:..bin\Release\MyAssembly.dll'. The system
> cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the 
> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
> available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
> Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Comment: this is probably a moot point, but it seems this used to work maybe with previous versions  of msbuild or something in the framework - it only behaved this way some time in the last 3-6 months and I wasn't able to use tasks distributed via nuget anymore.

Comment: Hi Michael, any update about this issue?

Comment: yup I haven't had a chance yet to go back and test using your solution, I'll do my best to get to it today (I ended up abandoning ILRepack tasks, but would like to go back to it if it'll work)

Comment: Sure. That is your choice and I am always here.

Comment: any update about this issue, please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the folder `bin\Debug\net48\` has the file `MyAssembly.dll`. In my side, it said that the file cannot be copied from `obj\Debug\net48\MyTask.dll` into `bin\Debug\net48\MyTask.dll` and it is locked by MSbuild.exe.

No matter for it or your issue, please try the following steps:

**1)** delete `bin` and `obj` folder first and also make sure the name of assembly dll is right.

**2)** then, remove these from `csproj` file:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyTask" AssemblyFile="bin\Debug\net48\MyAssembly.dll" />
<Target Name="SomeTask" AfterTargets="Build">
  <MyTask />
</Target>
```

**3)** close VS Instance, then restart your project, first, build your project.

**After that**, re-add the `SomeTask` custom target and then click `Build` button rather **Rebuild** Button. I have put both of them into the same project.

[image]

**Besides**, if you click `Rebuild`, the using task which loads the dll is used by `MSBuild.exe` and the msbuild cleans and re-copies `MyAssembly.dll` are at the same time. And they will conflict with each other. Also, the behavior is caused by that you have put the `UsingTask` in the same project. And the best way to test it is to create a new single project and then use `UsingTask`.

Add a detail:

To solve it, you should shut down the `msbuild.exe` process and then you could click **Rebuild** every time.

[image]